# How to get sound intensity of an audio input through terminal?

Tags: command-line, audio, pulseaudio

I want to know the intensity of the sound being heard by an audio in source like a mic or Line-in through Command line. 
Kinda like the progressbar under the mouse but in CLI.
[image]

```
audiointensity mic0
10
```

Kind of like connecting a mic with amplification circuit to Arduino through an analog pin 0 and doing a analogRead(0). So, you get a value within a particular like (0 to 1024) or (0 to 100) .

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want something like a [VU meter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VU_meter) - like [this one](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/applications/166700-all-i-want-simple-command-line-vu-meter.html), which uses `arecord` to display current volume.

Another option might be checking whether tha PulseAudio suite utilities (i.e. `pactl`, `pacat` etc.) could offer something useful  - although from my shallow understanding it probably doesn't.

Comment: I don't want the volume. I want the volume being heard by the mic. Like FFT but in intensity. Not volume. Like in **the bar being shown under the mouse pointer, not the sliders**.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question - check updated answer please.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what drivers you use.
If it's ALSA - you can use "alsamixer". It's a control panel of alsa devices with ncurses interface. To switch tab in this panel you can use key "tab".

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be "soundmeter", a Python script which reports averages of the volume at the command line. Details here: https://pypi.org/project/soundmeter/

Answer (score 0):

`arecord` do exactly this what you want.
For monitoring only, just use `/dev/null` for recorded file:

```
$ arecord -V stereo -r 44100 -f S16_LE -c 2 /dev/null
Recording WAVE '/dev/null' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
         +    #################### 72%|64%###################   +
```

For some statistics use `sox`:

```
$ sox -q -t alsa -d -n stats trim 0 5
             Overall     Left      Right
DC offset   0.000062  0.000042  0.000062
Min level  -0.783173 -0.783173 -0.718536
Max level   0.760437  0.760437  0.713348
Pk lev dB      -2.12     -2.12     -2.87
RMS lev dB    -12.67    -12.45    -12.91
RMS Pk dB      -8.16     -8.16     -8.68
RMS Tr dB     -23.90    -23.90    -23.89
Crest factor       -      3.28      3.18
Flat factor     0.00      0.00      0.00
Pk count           2         2         2
Bit-depth      16/16     16/16     16/16
Num samples     242k
Length s       5.035
Scale max   1.000000
Window s       0.050
```